# parse-ruby-client - How to send push notification from Rails website with this?

Tags: android, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, parse-platform

I would like to create a **Ruby on Rails** website that uses **Parse** https://github.com/adelevie/parse-ruby-client which I found at https://parse.com/docs/api_libraries . Really I would like the website and an *Android* phone to be able to communicate. But push notifications are my main priority.

Here is my problem: I cannot get parse-ruby-client to work at all. I am still fairly new to rails. When I try to install parse-ruby-client I get the following error:

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing parse-ruby-client:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for curl-config... no
checking for main() in -lcurl... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby
    --with-curl-dir
    --without-curl-dir
    --with-curl-include
    --without-curl-include=${curl-dir}/include
    --with-curl-lib
    --without-curl-lib=${curl-dir}/lib
    --with-curllib
    --without-curllib
extconf.rb:39:in `<main>':   Can't find libcurl or curl/curl.h (RuntimeError)

Try passing --with-curl-dir or --with-curl-lib and --with-curl-include
options to extconf.


Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9
.1/gems/patron-0.4.18 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/patron-0.
4.18/ext/patron/gem_make.out
```

I'm using rails 3.2.3 on heroku but really I'll use any version. I just want to get this to work. 
I thought perhaps the latest build had a problem so I downloaded a release but I'm not sure how to use it in the project since it is not a gem. 
This answer leads me to believe it is possible: https://parse.com/questions/parse-ruby-client-gem .
I did try to use the **Parse Rails Bootstrap** but could not get that to work either. I would like to.

Any kind of help would be appreciated. I have been stuck on this for a while. 
Are there easier or better ways to do this?
I want to use Rails.

Comment: This ended up being the answer gem install parse-ruby-client parse-ruby-client -- --with-curl-lib=C:\curl-7.21.0-devel-mingw32\bin --with-curl-include=C:\curl-7.21.0-devel-mingw32\include

Answer (score 2):

You do not seem to have the libcurl libraries installed.

```
ERROR:  Error installing parse-ruby-client:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for curl-config... no
checking for main() in -lcurl... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

Try installing them from your OS repos. Like for Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

Comment: I did manage to get it installed. However, now I am getting "SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate". I am not able to figure this out. I was hoping to host the Rails app on Heroku. Would that work if I just have a certificate in my lib folder?

Answer (score 0):

Put 
gem 'parse-ruby-client', git: 'https://github.com/adelevie/parse-ruby-client.git'
in your gem file and visit https://github.com/adelevie/parse-ruby-client/blob/master/example.rb for more example